# Spring Integration: Using Priority-Channel with Comparator doesn't unpack message

Tags: spring-integration, comparator, priority-queue, classcastexception

I am using spring integration `priority-channel` and I wanted to provide a custom `Comparator`.

```
<int:channel id="basedata.csv.income.sorting.channel" datatype="java.io.File">
    <int:priority-queue comparator="fileMessageComparator"/>
</int:channel>
```

Giving the `Comparator` with type message works fine:

```
@Component
public class FileMessageComparator implements Comparator<Message<File>> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Message<File> fileMessage1, Message<File> fileMessage2) {
        long fileLength1 = fileMessage1.getPayload().length();
        long fileLength2 = fileMessage2.getPayload().length();
        return Long.valueOf(fileLength2).compareTo(Long.valueOf(fileLength1));
    }
}
```

But what I also expected a comparator will work without type of message and the payload will be unpacked automatically:

```
@Component
public class FileMessageComparator implements Comparator<File> {
    @Override
    public int compare(File file1, File file2) {
        long fileLength1 = file1.length();
        long fileLength2 = file2.length();
        return Long.valueOf(fileLength2).compareTo(Long.valueOf(fileLength1));
    }
}
```

Stacktrace:

```
2018-02-19 11:35:38.243 ERROR 196 --- [oTaskExecutor-1] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: failed to send Message to channel 'basedata.csv.income.sorting.channel'; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.integration.channel.PriorityChannel$MessageWrapper cannot be cast to java.io.File, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=C:\Users\MHE\AppData\Local\Temp\ziptransformer\5caaddf0-a8e5-dbdf-6148-39ba60d5a4b8\Abrechnungen_Detailzeilen.csv, headers={zip_entryPath=, sequenceNumber=2, zipFileName=20161112, file_name=Abrechnungen_Detailzeilen.csv, sequenceSize=11, correlationId=e7b189fd-7910-d259-f25d-a3bcf4a855a9, file_originalFile=..\data\income\20161112.zip, basedataIndex=-1, id=966873e9-6461-ac1f-e8bb-62d0a9c64d5a, file_relativePath=20161112.zip, timestamp=1519036538145}]
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:464)
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:388)
at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:181)
at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:160)
at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:108)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:418)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:328)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:219)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:115)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:141)
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.BroadcastingDispatcher.invokeHandler(BroadcastingDispatcher.java:224)
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.BroadcastingDispatcher.access$000(BroadcastingDispatcher.java:56)
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.BroadcastingDispatcher$1.run(BroadcastingDispatcher.java:204)
at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:53)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.integration.channel.PriorityChannel$MessageWrapper cannot be cast to java.io.File
at package.FileMessageComparator.compare(FileMessageComparator.java:1)
at org.springframework.integration.channel.PriorityChannel$SequenceFallbackComparator.compare(PriorityChannel.java:155)
at org.springframework.integration.channel.PriorityChannel$SequenceFallbackComparator.compare(PriorityChannel.java:143)
at java.util.concurrent.PriorityBlockingQueue.siftUpUsingComparator(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.PriorityBlockingQueue.offer(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.integration.channel.QueueChannel.doSend(QueueChannel.java:91)
at org.springframework.integration.channel.PriorityChannel.doSend(PriorityChannel.java:128)
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:438)
... 17 more
```

In the past time it worked without defining Message in `Comparator`, a example I also found on [GitHub](https://github.com/spring-projects/Spring-Integration-in-Action/tree/master/siia-examples) I am using `Spring-Boot 2.0.0.RC1`

Answer (score 2):

PriorityChannel expects the whole Message (not just payload), so. . .

Your comparator should be

```
public class FileMessageComparator implements Comparator<Message<File>> {..}
```

Cheers

Comment: Hi Oleg, thanks for the message. Thats how I got it work. But when doing it, then the Comparator depends on Spring-Integration. In the past time you didn`t need to define Message<?>, then it unpacked the payload if it could.

Example: https://github.com/spring-projects/Spring-Integration-in-Action/blob/master/siia-examples/messages-channels/src/main/java/siia/channels/CustomerPriorityComparator.java

Comment: True, and I have hard recollection of the actual issue, but found this https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-2508 which I believe is at the core of a problem. But there is a silver lining. . . Message is no-longer in Spring Integration and was pulled into spring-messaging, so your comparator would not be SI dependent.

Comment: I think the sample in the book is wrong. Looking to the blaming history that code hasn’t been touched for 10 years: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blame/master/spring-integration-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/channel/PriorityChannel.java